# symfony2: debug service creation, service not being instantiated?

Tags: symfony, service, containers

I am new to symfony2.

I am trying to instantiate a service throug the container.

app/config/config.yml:

```
services:
    mci.service_registry:
        class: Mci\APIBundle\MciServiceRegistry

    mci.service_listener:
        class: Mci\APIBundle\EventListener\MciServiceListener
        tags:
            - { name: kernel.event_listener, event: kernel.controller, method: onKernelController }
        calls:
            - [setRegistry, ["@mci.service_registry"]]
```

MciServiceListener:

```
namespace Mci\APIBundle\EventListener;

class MciServiceListener
{
    public function __construct()
    {
      echo "CONSTRUCTING SERVICE LISTENER\n";
    }
}
```

Shouldn't I see the log output? 
To me it seems as the service is not being instantiated.

When I do `php app/console container:debug | grep mci` I get:

```
mci.service_listener                            container Mci\APIBundle\EventListener\MciServiceListener                                             
mci.service_registry                            container Mci\APIBundle\MciServiceRegistry
```

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, my bad,

there was a huuuuge typo in the php file
(it was not starting with